# Template composition: Base template from multiple templates

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

How can I do some kind of template inheritance in Word?

I have created different pieces of Word documents like header, footer, sidebar.
These pieces I want to compose into one single base template.
From that single base template, I create multiple other ones.

Reason is, that if I need to change a text, I need to only change it in one place, not in every document.

I've experimented with inserting linked objects, but if the content is changed, it doesn't get updated in the template where its linked in.
Quick Styles aren't a solid solution either.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  Think about storing these components as building blocks and using AutoText fields in your document templates to draw them in.  https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.